# Get the URL of the frontmost tab from Chrome on OS X?

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

Is there a way to do this to Chrome?

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
 return URL of front document as string
end tell
```

... doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no applescript support  the only way it can be done is through GUI scripting, I'm not sure how familiar you are with applescript but gui scripting is a bad practice to get into. so take this code with caution. it is also **important** that you have access for assistive devices ENABLED in your Universal Access preferences.

```
  tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Google Chrome"
            get value of text field 1 of tool bar 1 of window 1
        end tell
    end tell
  end tell
```

Comment: Woo! I just wrote the following script so I can more easily use PasswordMaker with Chrome, thanks to your answer!

tell application "System Events"
 tell application process "Google Chrome"
  set theURL to get value of text field 1 of tool bar 1 of window 1
 end tell
end tell
set domainparts to splitText(".", item 3 in splitText("/", theURL))
set topdom to joinText(".", {item ((count domainparts) - 1) of domainparts, item ((count domainparts)) of domainparts})
do shell script "/Users/dmd/bin/pmo " & topdom

Comment: you can't put code in comments they are just comments you can edit your question and put your final code at the bottom making sure you mark it

Answer (score 48):

Now that Chrome (7+) supports AppleScript, you can do this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    get URL of active tab of first window
end tell
```

Note: "first window" refers to the frontmost window.

Comment: Is there documentation for Chrome specific AppleScript commands? For example, if I want to do something like getting the HTML content of the active tab, where do I look for ways to doing it?

Comment: There isn't much documentation that I could find, except the dictionary that you can see by opening the Chrome app in Script Editor.

Comment: This stopped working in Chrome 103.0.5060.53.

Answer (score 7):

There is a simpler way to retrieve the URL.

`'tell application "Google Chrome" to return URL of active tab of front window'`

Tested and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

No Applescript support: [Issue 27468 - chromium - Applescript support for testing and scripting - Project Hosting on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27468)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the frontmost tab with this script:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set frontIndex to active tab index of front window
    get URL of tab frontIndex of front window
end tell
```

Hope I got this right. Try it out.

Comment: Or just `tell app "Google Chrome" to tell window 1 to URL of tab active tab index`. Or `tell app "Google Chrome" to URL of active tab of window 1`.