# Tracking Website usage using node-webkit

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, google-chrome, node-webkit

We are currently working on an **desktop application using node-webkit** where we need to track different usage statistics of user.

So far we have been **able to capture processes information** ( which process is running for how much duration - like chrome, notepad++, VLC player, skype etc ) for all platforms i.e Windows, Mac and Linux.

Our next stop is tracking website usage statistics. For this we had some success ( Chrome and safari ) in MAC platform using AppleScript ( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483033/get-the-url-of-the-frontmost-tab-from-chrome-on-os-x), [link](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/2013-how-to-get-frontmost-tab%E2%80%99s-url-and-title-of-various-browsers/) ) by running this **Applescript** from Node's Child Process.

---

**What we have in hand ?**

We know exactly when some browser application ( Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE ) is active. Also, we have **PID, Window Title, Executable Name** related to current active browser application.

---

**What we want:**

Listen to tab change or creation event and get the url of active tab for the active browser. ( On Linux and Windows only )

---

**What options do we have ( or the one's I know of )**

**1.** Using some nodejs api which already incorporates c/c++ add ons ( like [winctl](https://github.com/thraaawn/winctl), which is used for detecting active window change in windows )

**Question** :
My effort in finding any such node api has gone futile. **Does anyone know of any such api or has worked with a similar api?**

**2.** Using Command Line ( Node Child Process and Exec function )

**Question** :
Is there any way i can detect active tab change through command Line or shell script ? ( I have also explored this option but I am still far from what i want to accomplish )

**3.** Using C/C++ Add ons in nodejs

**Question** :
This is something which i would try to avoid as i know its not trivial to create C/C++ add on's for node. But still as a last resort, has anyone used any c/c++ module for the similar purpose. If yes, can you please point me to the same.

**4.** Writing Separate Browser Extension ( For Chrome, Firefox and IE ) - **Last Resort**, since we want to have just one app which can installed on user machine rather than multiple extensions and softwares.

**No Question Here**

Any help / Suggestion in this regards are most welcome. Thanks in Advance